# Entity Framework: store (and recover) from base classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using **c#**, and **EF**, **linq**. I have this base model:

```
public class BaseModel {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

these classes:

```
public class ModelA: BaseModel { 
    public virtual string PropertyA { get; set; } 
}

public class ModelB: BaseModel {
     public virtual string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class Model: BaseModel {
    public virtual BaseModel Entity     { get; set; }
    public virtual string    EntityType { get; set; }
}
```

these configurations on `DbContext`:

```
public IDbSet<ModelA> ModelsA { get; set; }
public IDbSet<ModelB> ModelsB { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Model>  Models  { get; set; }
```

creating and saving instances on this way:

```
var modelA = new ModelA { Id=1, PropertyA = "ValueA" };
dbContext.ModelsA.Add(modelA);    

var modelB = new ModelB { Id=2, PropertyB = "ValueB" };
dbContext.ModelsB.Add(modelB);

var model1 = new Model { Entity = modelA, EntityType = nameof(ModelA) };
dbContext.Models.Add(model1);

var model2 = new Model { Entity = modelB, EntityType = nameof(ModelB) };
dbContext.Models.Add(model2);
```

Exist a way to recover instances of `ModelA`/`ModelB` directly from `Models`?, I mean, a kind of:

```
var modelsAList = dbContext.Models
                       .Where(m=>m.EntityType=='ModelA')
                       .Select(m=>m.Entity as ModelA)
                       .ToList();
```

( the above code does not work, only to illustrate what I need )

Comment: Well, the code doesn't compile (you should work on your posts), but once you fix the syntax errors, it actually works. The only problem is that the `EntityType` field is redundant, since TPH creates `Discriminator` column for the same purpose.